# canvasぴったりのサイズで、Electronのウィンドウを作る方法を教えてください

Tags: typescript, electron, game-development

Phaser 3でゲームを作っています。
ページの中心にcanvasを作成し、その中にゲーム画面を表示しています。

Electronのウィンドウにcanvasを表示します。
その際、canvasが拡大も縮小もされないように表示したいです。

canvasのサイズは `width: 800px, height: 600px` です。
　
そこで、以下のようなコードを書きました。

```js
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: (process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION as unknown) as boolean,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });
```

以下のウィンドウが表示されました。オレンジ色の部分がcanvasです。

[image: 画面]

Developer Toolsで確認したところ、`width: 800px, height: 600px` になっており正しいです。

しかし、`<body>` のサイズが `width: 777px, height: 604px` になっていました。

この値は、Electronのウィンドウ作成時に指定した `width: 800px, height: 600px` と異なります。

そのせいで、スクロールバーが表示されてしまいました。
なぜこのような動作になるか、分かる人はいますか？

`<body>` のサイズを `width: 800px, height: 600px` にするには、どのように修正すれば良いですか？

Electronのバージョンは9.2.1です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語で質問したら解決しました。
`useContentSize: true,` ですね。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63937529/how-do-i-create-an-electron-window-the-same-size-as-a-canvas